# Laravel 4: Scope method only accepts first parameter?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, scope

this is inside of my Controller:

```
$a="A";
$b="B";
$res = MyModel::getBook($a,$b);
```

Inside of "MyModel":

```
public function scopegetBook($a,$b)

{

var_dump($a,$b);
return null;

}
```

This only outputs "A" and an object with generic db data, "B" is missing.

Can't scope-methods handle more than 1 parameter? Or do i have to put $a and $b inside an array?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the first parameter in any `scope` method is `Query Builder` instance passed by `Laravel` and you should use other parameters from the second index, for example:

```
public function scopeGetBook($query, $a, $b)
{
    //...
}
```

In this method, the first parameter will be passed by Framework and you may use other parameters if you call it like this:

```
Modelname::getBook($param1, $param2); // Replace Modelname with real Model name
```

Here the `$param1` will be received in the `$a` and `$param2` will be received in the `$b`. Also notice the method name after scope is `GetBook` not `getBook`.